# Is it possible to have SSL Labs score A as well as chrome not say "obsolete cryptography"?

Tags: iis

I am running an Azure Web role, I have tried hundreds of permutations of cipher suites and the only time I get chrome not to say "obsolete encryption" SSL Labs scores a B. I can get an A but then chrome says "obsolete encyption". Am I going mad?

Does anyone know what the "correct" settings should be?

More information:
I can get chrome to say "uses modern cryptography" if I use TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 , but SSL labs scores this a B because it uses "weak Diffie-Hellman (DH) key exchange parameters "

This scores and A in SSL Labs

`TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA`

but Chrome says "obsolete cryptography" and appears to use TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA

Comment: https://cipherli.st/

Comment: alas no list for windows

Comment: https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/Default.aspx

Comment: I've been playing around with IISCrypto, but I can't find the sweet spot that  both Chrome and SSL Labs agree on. Any clues?

Comment: On balance having read more about logjam, I wonder if I am better off ignoring what chrome says and going with SSL Labs? Then pointing anybody that complains at the SSL Labs report. Thoughts?

Comment: You need to drop all the ones that end with "SHA" and keep only the "SHA256", "SHA384" etc.

Comment: I couldn't even connect to the server when I did that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer in the end is not really, without an ECDSA certificate.

https://community.qualys.com/thread/15230

> In order to escape catch-22, consider Chrome "modern cryptography" for
>   traditional DHE a security theater, since it doesn't show DH size
>   (ironically, even Internet Explorer does). The current stable Chrome
>   shows "modern" on https://dh768.serverhello.com but Chrome 45 will
>   fail with Server has a weak ephemeral Diffie-Hellman public key
>   message (ERR_SSL_WEAK_SERVER_EPHEMERAL_DH_KEY)
>
> Now the real answer: obtain ECDSA certificate. Many Microsoft IIS problems disappear automatically, including Chrome cryptography treatment.